# Abelian extensions are ray class fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

There is a theorem that states that for any algebraic number field $K$ and any integral ideal in its ring of integers $\mathfrak{m} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$, there exists an extension $L$ of $K$ (the ray class field) such that $\textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is isomorphic to the ray class group $J^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}$.

This group is necessarily Abelian.

But conversely, if $E$ is any Abelian extension of $K$, does there always exist some integral ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ such that

$$J^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}} \cong \textrm{Gal}(L/K)?$$

Comment: To each quotient of $J^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}$ there is an abelian extension and all the abelian extensions appear this way. The homomorphism $J^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}\to J/P$  is surjective because any ideal class has a representative coprime with $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: When neglecting the archimedean places (primes), the ray class field of K relative to $\mathfrak M$ is the *maximal* abelian extension of K unramified outside M. When taking them into account, ramification at the archimedean primes must be defined, but it's just a question of book keeping. See e.g. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the LHS is always at least as big as the class group but the RHS could be smaller (for example trivial). The correct claim is that any Abelian extension is a subfield of a ray class field

Comment: Very nice. One thing: Is it easily seen that $\lvert J^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}} \rvert \geq \rvert J/P \rvert$? I can't seem to see it.